# Need help identifying the value of a tantalum capacitor marked 226C

Tags: capacitor, identification, markings, tantalum

Recently, there was an accident. A capacitor blew and left a fixable problem. In the following picture, there is a surface mount capacitor whose capacitance value is unknown. Please help me.

Worst case is I can remove the capacitor and use a measurement tool, but I wish not to compromise the board that has the same capacitor just to identify this value.

[image: photo of capacitor]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"226" = "22" followed by 6 zeros, in pF. 22,000,000 pF = 22µF

"C" = 16V

See: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/capacitors/capacitor-codes-markings.php

When you order a replacement, consider using a tantalum polymer capacitor instead of a classical tantalum-MnO2 ("solid tantalum") type since polymer caps are much less likely to ignite. (This is due to the MnO2 being an oxidizer that supports combustion when things go wrong, while polymers don't do that)